# Issue in the PHP associative array logic implemented

Tags: php

I am new to php, I have the below code  And the fnction output is as given below.

```
public function getNLastDailyBuilds()
    {
        ksort( $this->deployments['list'] );
        $history = array();

        foreach( $this->deployments['list'] as $buildId => $build ) {

            $job = $build->getBuildDetails( $this->teamCIDB, $this->jenkins );
            $infos = $this->jenkins->parseMavenBuildInfo( $job );
            if ( $build->isOngoing() && !$build->getStatus()  ) {
                continue;
            }
            if ( array_key_exists( 'shortDescription', $infos['causes'] ) && ( $infos['causes']['shortDescription'] == 'Started by timer' )) {

                if ( array_key_exists( $build->getDateASString(), $history ) && (($history[$build->getDateASString()]['status'] == 'SUCCESS' ) || ($history[$build->getDateASString()]['status'] == 'UNSTABLE' )))

                    $history[$build->getDateAsString()] = array( 'date' => $build->getDateASString(), 'id' => $buildId, 'Auto' => 1, 'status' => $build->getStatus(), 'description' => $build->getDescription(), 'defect' => $build->getDefectID() );


                else {
                    if ( !array_key_exists( $build->getDateAsString(), $history ))

                        $history[$build->getDateAsString()] = array( 'date' => $build->getDateASString(), 'id' => $buildId, 'Auto' => 1, 'status' => $build->getStatus(), 'description' => $build->getDescription(), 'defect' => $build->getDefectID() );
                }   

            } else {

                if ( !array_key_exists( $build->getDateAsString(), $history ) || ($history[$build->getDateASString()]['status'] == 'ABORTED' ))

                    $history[$build->getDateAsString()] = array( 'date' => $build->getDateASString(), 'id' => $buildId, 'Auto' => 0, 'status' => $build->getStatus(), 'description' => $build->getDescription(), 'defect' => $build->getDefectID() );
            }
        }
        mydebug( "NLAST=".print_r( $history, TRUE ));
        return $history;
    }
```

It prints the output as below

```
    NLAST=Array
(   
    [2018-02-27] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2018-02-27
            [id] => 196
            [Auto] => 0
            [status] => FAILURE
            [description] =>
            [defect] => 0
        )

    [2018-02-28] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2018-02-28
            [id] => 197
            [Auto] => 1
            [status] => FAILURE
            [description] =>
            [defect] => 0
        )

)
```

When I have more than one [id] for date 2018-02-28 it is not over writing the  array. For example , ksort( $this->deployments['list'] ); will have mutiple entries for same date like 197,198,200 like that. 
But the result array brings the first entry when we print , but I need the last entry which came from deployments['list'] for the date 2018-02-28.

Comment: Your code checks if the date already exists as an array key before adding the data to the array. It seems like you should just remove this check to get the latest entries.

Comment: If you can give me the modified code , that would be great